# Não estou conseguindo ultilizar o ngFor para trazer as informações de um objeto

Tags: angular, typescript

**html:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Foto</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Propriedade 1</th>
        <th>Propriedade 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let funcionario of Funcionarios">
        <td>{{ funcionarios.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ funcionarios.nome }}</td>
        <td><img [src]="objeto.foto" alt="Foto"></td>
        <td>{{ funcionarios.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ funcionarios.subobjeto.propriedade1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ funcionarios.subobjeto.propriedade2 }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Funcionarios } from 'src/app/funcionarios';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-funcionarios',
  templateUrl: './funcionarios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./funcionarios.component.css']
})

export class FuncionariosComponent {
  funcionarios: Funcionarios = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: "Alonzo Birden",
      foto: "https://robohash.org/praesentiumomnisdolore.png?size=50x50&set=set1",
      email: "abirden0@mac.com",
      subobjeto: {
        propriedade1: "Valor 1",
        propriedade2: "Valor 2"
      }
    },

  ];
}
```

**model**

```
class funcionarios {
    id: number;
    nome: string;
    foto: string;
    email: string;
    subobjeto: {
      propriedade1: string;
      propriedade2: string;
    };
  
    constructor(id: number, nome: string, foto: string, email: string, subobjeto: { propriedade1: string, propriedade2: string }) {
      this.id = id;
      this.nome = nome;
      this.foto = foto;
      this.email = email;
      this.subobjeto = subobjeto;
    }
  }
  
export interface Funcionarios {
    
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Gabriel, acredito que o problema esteja no seu html, no seu componente você está instanciando o a váriavel com o nome "funcionarios", mas no seu ngFor você está utilizando sua interface "Funcionarios", o correto é utilizar sua variavel que você instanciou no component.ts...

component.ts

```
export class FuncionariosComponent {
  funcionarios: Funcionarios[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: "Alonzo Birden",
      foto: "https://robohash.org/praesentiumomnisdolore.png?size=50x50&set=set1",
      email: "abirden0@mac.com",
      subobjeto: {
        propriedade1: "Valor 1",
        propriedade2: "Valor 2"
      }
    },
  ];
}
```

html

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Foto</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Propriedade 1</th>
        <th>Propriedade 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let funcionario of funcionarios">
        <td>{{ funcionario .id }}</td>
        <td>{{ funcionario .nome }}</td>
        <td><img [src]="funcionario.foto" alt="Foto"></td>
        <td>{{ funcionario.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ funcionario.subobjeto.propriedade1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ funcionario.subobjeto.propriedade2 }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Uma melhoria que você pode fazer no seu código é utilizar uma interface para criar seu model "Funcionario"

funcionario.ts

```
export inteface Funcionario {
    id: number;
    nome: string;
    foto: string;
    email: string;
    subobjeto: SubObjeto;
}
```

sub-objeto.ts

```
export interface SubObjeto {
    propriedade1: string;
    propriedade2: string;
}
```

Comment: Caso queira ver o código e o resultado:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rug1be?file=src%2Fmain.ts